# only one weapon type per aircraft?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Veterans will recall that old skool Interceptors could be armed with two distinct weapon types, traditionally a stand-off tickler and a close-in sledgehammer. I just upgraded my Interceptor weaponry for the first time and was surprised to discover that it seems you can only have one weapon type at a time.

Is there any way to put two weapons on one craft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one weapon per interceptor.

I recommend you to have at least two interceptors in each region. One with killing weapon and other with disabling weapon (EMP Cannon)

Comment: why would you want killing weapon?

Comment: To be honest first I started to put the biggest weapons available but now has changed my mind and I've configured most of my interceptors with EMP Cannon...

Answer (score 2):

You are right; an interceptor has only a single weapon system.